# Online publications in CVs

Tags: resume

Do you think it's a good idea to put online publications on your CV? I am talking about articles published on sites like DZone.com and the alike.

If it is a good idea, how, in what form should I include these things, if it's not, why?

Comment: If these articles are still easily accessible (no registration required)  and relevant I would put live links into your document file.

Comment: Only include real publications dzone looks like a content farm

Comment: As Pepone says, only link to reputable publications. Linking to dzone would not count for much. It is no different from print publications: you link to what you have written in publications of name, not to an advertorial or to an article in some fake (maybe pay to publish) magazine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It shows your skills, knowledge and communication. If you have a lot of these, pick the best ones and write something like "For example". Especially if you live in a country where a 1-2 page resume is expected rather than a long CV. If you are in a country where CVs are expected or in academia, length isn't a big issue. (In the US, a lot of people don't understand the distinction between a resume and CV which is why I mention this)

Personally, I keep [much of my CV online](http://www.coderanch.com/t/660334/Wiki/Bio-Jeanne-Boyarsky) so I can list details without overloading my resume. (ex: every public talk/article/etc). And I've been contacted based on just that page.

Another thought it to provide a tinyurl to a page that lists everything and pick some to be on your resume. The reason I favor a tinyurl over embedded links is that someone might print your resume and no longer have something to click on.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to add publications to your profile on LinkedIn (and it can generate a pdf CV for you); generally I think it's a good idea.

I would say mostly it depends on the role you are applying for with that CV (if not speculative) If they are interested in articles or the content of those articles, then definitely. If your views in those articles goes against what the company stands for (if this is applicable) then perhaps don't mention them. For example, if one of your articles criticises corporate culture and your CV is viewed by a corporate recruiter... perhaps think again.